Find the probability that an odd number appears on the die.
On a normal standard die one of the 21 dots from any one of the six faces is removed at random with each dot equally likely to be chosen. If the die is then rolled, then find the probability that the odd number appears.
In The answer in the textbook they have assumed all of the dots to be distinguishable and the answer by simply taking the cases when the dot is removed from an odd face and when removed from an even face
$$((2+4+6)/(21))*(4/6)+((1+3+5)/(21))*(2/6)$$
What I want to ask is that why did they assume all the dots to be distinguishable
What I want to ask that if I would have to solve this problem in real life then I think all the dots are not distinguishable so for example in a normal dice the face with 5 dots all the 4 corner dots would look same and we can only distinguish between the central dot and a corner dot
Is there some mistake in the given solution or am I thinking in the wrong way ?
Any help is appreciated
Thankyou

It says clearly that each dot is equally likely to be chosen (for removal) so distinguishability doesn't enter the picture at all. We are only concerned about the parity change of the face after a dot is removed.

If you prefer, you could assume that each dot on a given face is indistinguishable from the other dots on that face.  Nothing incorrect about that, but it complicates the problem since now the probability that a given face is chosen to lose a dot is not the same for each face.  The probability that the $6-$face is chosen is $6$ times the probability that the $1-$ face is chosen.

The dot on the 5 face nearest to the corner where faces 1, 4 and 5 meet is most definitely distinguishable from the dot on the 5 face nearest to the corner where faces 3, 5 and 6 meet.

@DanielMathias ok understood , thankyou
